# Split amount with defined precision and no rounding errors

Tags: javascript

I needed a way to split an amount (in dollars) between one or more "buckets", for lack of a better word. It needed to have the standard two decimal precision a dollar amount should, but every penny needed to be accounted for.

To illustrate the problem, consider this example:

$200 split 3 ways. If you round down, each amount is $66.66 and you end up 2 cents short, but if you round up, each amount is $66.67 and you're 2 cents over. The answer, of course, is to have one $66.66 and the other two $66.67. That's easy enough for a human to reason, but trying to make bit of JavaScript understand that is kind of a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the function I came up with:

```
function SplitTotal( totalAmount, numberToSplit, precision ) {
  var precisionFactor = Math.pow(10, precision);
  var remainderFactor = 1 / precisionFactor;

  var splitAmount = Math.ceil( totalAmount / numberToSplit * precisionFactor ) / precisionFactor;
  var remainder = Math.round( (splitAmount * numberToSplit - totalAmount) * precisionFactor ) / precisionFactor;

  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numberToSplit; i++) {
    result.push( (remainder >= remainderFactor) ?
                     Math.round( (splitAmount - remainderFactor) * precisionFactor ) / precisionFactor :
                     splitAmount );
    remainder = Math.round( (remainder - remainderFactor) * precisionFactor ) / precisionFactor;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The code is a little convoluted, because JavaScript handles floating point numbers atrociously. In order to get a nice, precise decimal amount, you need to multiply the amount by what I call here a "precision factor", which is just some exponent of 10, round the resulting number, and then divide by that precision factor to get back to the original decimal precision.

Even though I only needed 2 decimal spaces of precision, I made the precision easily definable, so this can work for more applications that just dollar amounts. If you want just integers, you can specify a precision of 0.

**Ex: $235.38 divided 7 ways:**

```
> SplitTotal(235.38, 7, 2)

[33.62, 33.62, 33.62, 33.63, 33.63, 33.63, 33.63]
```